# Running a shell command and saving the response to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell

I have a bunch of directories, named like this:

- 5553_DirHere
- 5554_DirHere
- 5555_DirHere

How can I run a shell command, to find all directories with the name "5554"?

The shell script would be something like:

`find /mnt/Desktop  -type d -name "5554*"`

Then save the output to a variable

This is what I have tried:

```
const getDownloadPath = name => {
const folderDir = 5554;
  exec('find /mnt/Desktop -type d -name ${folderDir}*', function(err, stdout, stderr)
 {
 if(err) console.error(stderr);
 const singleFolder = stdout;
 });
   return `${config.path}/${stdout}`;
 };
};
```

Comment: Did you mean to interpolate `name` into the string passed in as the first argument to `exec`? If so, you may have mistyped and used single quotes instead of backticks.

Comment: Thank you Wing, I have made a small edit. I'm not sure if I'm using the ${}-notation correct. If I do it like it says, will the final output be "find /mnt/Desktop -type d -name 5554*"?

Comment: You have to use `${...}` with backticks (`\`\``). You may also need to enclose the pattern passed to `-name` with quotes to prevent expansion of the wildcard. The first argument to `exec` should look like this: `\`find /mnt/Desktop -type d -name '${folderDir}*'\``. At runtime with the string interpolated, the resultant command will be `find /mnt/Desktop -type d -name '5554*'`.

Comment: I ended up not using 'child_process', as the find command took way to long. Instead, I used [file system](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options), works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Find' command can be slow when searching larger directories. I used [file-system](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options), which works perfectly.